# My Developer Quit, How to Edit and continue development on an ipa file (Half Built iOS App)

Tags: ios, iphone, ipa, ios7.1

The Developer I was working with quit halfway through the project and all I have is an .ipa file.  The File installs correctly in all the test devices.  I need some final changes to the app before I can publish it to the app store.

My question is Is the Ipa file connected only to that developer / his xCode ?  He was using my Apple Developer account.

Can any other developer I hire start with the Ipa file and edit the app?  The changes I need are adding a Msg box(Confirmation) and correcting some typos.

Alternatively to continue development on the app from this point forward what do I need to get  from the company, I'd rather not go back to starting from scratch again.

Comment: As long as you have the source this should not be a problem, you can retract any developerment certificates and profiles. You new developer can create new ones.

Comment: You cannot edit an IPA file. You should get the project source code to continue development.

Comment: Please check this, it may help you

http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1594/possibilities-for-reverse-engineering-an-ipa-file-to-its-source

Comment: I do not have the Source codes / files , All I have is the .ipa file.  Thanks @AliRaza That link and the info in there look interesting. I will investigate it further.

Comment: Please check this, it may help you 

http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1594/possibilities-for-reverse-engineering-an-ipa-file-to-its-source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do anything with an IPA file, it is the compiled version of your project. You need the source code to continue any development.

Maybe you can find a way to deassemble an IPA file, but it is an extreme case and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Ismail, Thanks, I was fearing this would be the case, Looks like an ipa is like an EXE file, cannot be edited. :( I will explore the decrypting links that other people have given up there.

Answer (score 0):

Get the source code from your developer. Only with that, you can continue further development.

Comment: Sorry Hawkeye, The Developer quit, Not responding to emails or anything other communication. So that's not an option. All I have is an ipa file